# Facebook app creation issue while retrieving itunes appid

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps

I am creating a Facebook App in Facebook Developer Account.

I have already created my app in my Apple developer account. I want to add Facebook login, Facebook sharing, Like etc. feature to my iOS app. So I am creating Facebook app in my Facebook developer account to obtain Facebook AppID and use it in my iOS app to accomplish the features.

In Facebook developer account I have created App and when I am giving reference of App BundleID (for iOS platform) then there is no issue with it. But when I am giving valid "iPhone Store ID" and "iPad Store ID" Facebook giving an error like written below.

"We were unable to retrieve your iPad Store ID from the iTunes App Store. Please double-check your ID and try again later."

This issue is occurring after Facebook recently changed it's layout. However there is no issue with my already created Apps on Facebook Developer account.

Thanks,

Comment: I have the same issue. did you solved it in any way?

Comment: @DanutPralea It has been a long time but did you find the reason please?

Comment: don't remember, sorry